# How to forward request in Yii2 framework?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2

So in most modern MVC frameworks there's a way to forward a request from one controller to another and return the response.
This how you do it in the Symfony framework:

```
return $this->forward('App\Controller\SignupController::postAction');
```

How do you do the same thing in the Yii2 framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return Yii::$app->runAction('controller/action');
```